# nodejs exception handling when loading modules

Tags: node.js, error-handling

how can i have a error handeling when i load a module in node.js
assume something like this:

```
mysql = require('mysql') ;
```

i want to handle errors more gracefully when there is a error loading mysql module.
something like this:

```
try: 
mysql = require('mysql') ;
catch(e):
console.log("there is a error loading module X");
```

another part of question is im looking for a way to load modules based on the Host operating system. for example load some modules on linux and others on windows.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
try {
  var mysql = require('mysql');
} catch(e) {
  console.log('error loading mysql module', e);
};
```

Loading modules based on OS can be done with checking `os.platform()`:

```
var platform = require('os').platform();
if (platform === 'linux') {
  ...
}
else
if (platform === 'windows') { // not sure if its called `windows` because I don't have a Windows machine
  ...
};
```

Comment: its win32 for windows by the way

Answer (score 0):

Used you express? If yes, you can try the error 500 handling :

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.log("this is an error");
});
```